# Name property in ConvertTo-XML

Tags: xml, powershell, pscustomobject

I've the following XML Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property>
      <Property Name="CustomerName">MyCustomerName</Property>
      <Property Name="Environment">Integration</Property>
      <Property Name="isVdi">false</Property>
    </Property>
    <!-- ... (Continues here, but I cut if off since it has nothing to do with the problem) -->
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

I generate this code by:

```bsh
$customerInformation = [PSCustomObject]@{
    CustomerName = $CustomerName;
    Environment  = $Environment;
    isVdi        = $isVdi;
}
```

What I would love is to give the `<Property>` tag that is around the object a name.

For example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Objects>
  <Object>
    <Property Name="CustomerInformation"> //Here I want to add the "CustomerInformation"
      <Property Name="CustomerName">MyCustomerName</Property>
      <Property Name="Environment">Integration</Property>
      <Property Name="isVdi">false</Property>
    </Property>
  </Object>
</Objects>
```

But I don't know how to do it.I'm not even sure if its possible, or if I have to use the `type` attribute. I'm kinda new to XML and would be happy to get some help here.

**What I've tried so far:**

- Tried to find solutions with Google.
- Tried to create the XML manually (could probably work, but isn't really what I want since it would become more and more complicate to maintain a clean code

I also thought about simply adding another Property into the object and then name it like `name="CustomerInformation"` and let im empty, but it would be better if its on the top level of the object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nest that custom object in another custom object:

```
$customerInformation = [PSCustomObject]@{
    'CustomerInformation' = [PSCustomObject]@{
        'CustomerName' = $CustomerName
        'Environment'  = $Environment
        'isVdi'        = $isVdi
    }
}
```

then convert that structure:

```
$xml = $customerInformation | ConvertTo-Xml -Depth 2
```

Note, however, that you *must* add the parameter `-Depth` with a value >1 for this to work. The default value for that parameter is 1, which would cause the following error because it didn't convert the entire object hierarchy:

```
ConvertTo-Xml : Unexpected end of file has occurred. The following elements are
not closed: Object, Objects. Line 7, position 16.
At line:1 char:31
+ $xml = $customerInformation | ConvertTo-Xml
+                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertTo-Xml], XmlException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Xml.XmlException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertToXmlCommand
```